# Typo in the developer story wizard

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

While making my history on Stack Overflow I noticed a grammatical error in the text under description:

[image: Stack Overflow Grammatical Mistake]

You'll notice that it says "Which projects are you most proud off?" which this should actually be of. My question is how to report this and where?

Comment: Has this been fixed just now? I can see the box when trying to add a new Education entry to my Developer Story, but it doesn't have the error.

Comment: Were you using a mobile device?

Comment: It appears when you first create your jobs profile. Since I just created the account I can't go back to the initial description creation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in the right place. Thanks for the report!

I pushed the fix and it will go live with the next production build. (Today? Over the weekend? Monday? It's a mystery. ;))

Comment: I'm pretty proud off my response time here.

Comment: What took you so long?

Comment: @Bart It's Friday. I was in Iceland.